# React router switch into switch /nested route?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm making a react App and i'm having issues where i must have route inside route, and i'm struggling with it.

Here how it goes :

1 ) you either face the page login or the home if you are logged in.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

2 ) the home page is composed of navbar, dashboard, and footer with routes route that switch the dashboard components with specific components like news, planning, etc.

````
const Home = () => (
 <div className='container-ome'>
   <Header />
   <Router>
     <Switch>
       <Dashboard />
       <Route exact path='/newspost' component={Newspost} />
       <Route exact path='/newslist' component={Newslist} />
       <Route exact path='/user' component={User} />
     </Switch>
   </Router>
   <Footer />
 </div>
);

export default Home;
```


3 ) The other components will have infos, and a link to get back to the dashboard

```const Newspost = () => (
 <div className='container-newspost'>
   <h1> Newpost Title</h1>
   <Link to='/'>back to dashboard</Link>
 </div>
);```

Nothing works like i would, what did i missed ? 
Should i declare al my routes in app ?

Be gentle i'm a noobie :(

Thanks in advance
````

Comment: please explain what exactly your question is. What happenes when you click a link? Why do you have a BrowserRouter and a Router?

Comment: Well, what i would like is a switch into another switch, the first one if login or homepage, and then the contain of homepage switch, between the nav and the footer.
Should i declare all my routes in app.js ?
For the browserrouter, i guess i just forget to delete one.

Comment: ok i found a way to solve my problem ! thanks anyway you can close this sorry for this

Comment: @JéromeBORGA Please share the way you found here. I have almost the same problem..

Comment: sorry for delay ! 
What i did is change my router to browserrouter and i deleted the nested switch, i'll just make login game redirect.